# Verify is (no longer) a valid API name

Tags: api, google-sheets, usps

I'm using the USPS API for address verification. For my purposes, I made a tool in Google Sheets to automate the lookup process. Type or paste FirmName/Address1/Address2/City/State in the appropriate cells, and formulas build a request that looks like this:

```
=IMPORTDATA(http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="XXXXXXXXX"><Address ID="0"><FirmName></FirmName><Address1></Address1><Address2>501 MAIN ST</Address2><City>WABASH</City><State>IN</State><Zip5></Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>)
```

This worked great for about 4 weeks. Then one morning I opened the Sheet, and instead of a normal response, the output read

```
<Error><Number>80040B1A</Number><Description>API Authorization failure. Verify is not a valid API name for this protocol.</Description><Source>USPSCOM::DoAuth</Source></Error>
```

As long as the XML is properly formed, this is the only response I get. If I change my USER ID to some fake number it gives no related error. I've also tried the other APIs and all give the same API Authorization failure.

If I paste the XML request into a browser, it gives a valid response, so I know my API key is still working. I had shared my Google Sheet with several co-workers, who were using their own API keys. They hit the same error.

I've been in contact with USPS Support, and though they aren't very forthcoming, they haven't indicated that they've blocked Google servers from accessing their API. I "reported a problem" in Google Sheets also, but I don't expect to hear anything from Google.

If I couldn't get it to work in the first place, that would be one thing. It's that it worked fine for weeks that has me stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: The format of the IMPORTDATA is wrong. The URL should be quote enclosed, by the other hand it should be a valid URL. See [IMPORTDATA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Since it worked fine for a time, and the API call still works independent of the Google sheet, and you've tried other APIs with similar results, it seems the problem is probably Google-sheet related.

The only problem I notice is that the URL is not enclosed in quotation marks. The main snares are stated in this excerpt from the [IMPORTDATA docs page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en):

> Syntax
>   IMPORTDATA(url)
>
> url - The url from which to fetch the .csv or .tsv-formatted data, including protocol (e.g. http://).
>
> > The value for url must either be enclosed in quotation marks or be a reference to a cell containing the appropriate text.
>
> Notes
>   A maximum of 50 IMPORTDATA calls are supported on a single spreadsheet.

(You can find other interesting information and data in the [help forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/docs/importdata$20error).)

I suggest you construct the URL in a separate cell so you can bring in field data such as the city and state. I don't think that will require you to use quotation marks, which might be needed since your URL construction has quotation-enclosed parts.

Then, pass the information to IMPORTDATA using a cell reference.

---

(Full disclosure: I work for [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com), an address verification provider with additional features and uptime guarantees.)

Comment: Yes, I was constructing the URL with a concatenation formula that combined URL text with cell data. IMPORTDATA stopped working for a couple weeks, then started working again. I agree that it was mostly likely a Google Sheets issue and not an API issue, although that's just a guess.